# Fill a TextBox according to query result and bind it before insertion in DetailsView

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net-2010

[image]

I want to fill (visits) textbox with a number according to a query after input the (fullName) textbox 
I am using a detailsview, i tried but it always return '0' in insertion 
this is my code behind in VB.NET to find the matching if the name exist the increase the number of visits and if does not found any matching number of visits will be initially '1'.
NOTE: the code works perfectly only the problem i had is to bind the number of visits into (Visits) textbox before insertion the record.

```
 Protected Sub DetailsView1_ItemInserting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewInsertEventArgs) Handles DetailsView1.ItemInserting
    Dim NameOfPatients As TextBox = DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox1")
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection
    Dim sda As SqlDataAdapter
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ClinicConn").ConnectionString
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Patients_tab WHERE FullName = '" & NameOfPatients.Text & "'"
    sda = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn)
    conn.Open()
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    sda.Fill(ds)
    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        VisitCount = Val(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count) + 1
    Else
        VisitCount = 1
    End If
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: You desperately need to address how you handle your queries. They need to be paramterized. What you have here is wide open to sql injection and my friend [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) loves code like this. For the question at hand I have no idea what you mean by "insertion record", there is no insert posted here.

Comment: I found the solution it just by canceling the DetailsView method and make a simple insert code behind with TextBox tool instead

Comment: I hope you also read up about parameterization of queries. Glad you found a solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because apparently the OP solved this.

Comment: @SeanLange  `VisitCount = Val(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count) + 1` this line gives me total number of visits 
so if I have 5 visits for example and I delete (Visit No.2) ,  then i inserted a new visit for the same patient i want to be 6 NOT 5

Comment: You should not be storing this value in the first place. It is painless to calculate the count. You should just count the number of visits when you display it. I really don't understand what you are trying to do here though.